# Creating a transparent see-through or texturized font style

Tags: css, html, fonts

Is it possible to specify a font style (font color, etc.) so that instead of using a solid color I could:

- Have an HTML element on top of another, and make the font transparent, so I can have the text cut through the top element and see the contents of the bottom element through the area of the letters?
- Specify text with images (not animated for instance/at least), so I can use textured text instead of solid colors?

Is it possible or not, using any CSS level/version, or HTML5, or some native web browser specification?

Is it possible to detect the area of each letter at least using Canvas, or should it still be done fully manually, or impossible in plain HTML/HTML5/CSS?

Comment: Interesting question, although I don't think this is possible (except maybe with IE's proprietary `filter` stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first one you are talking about is similar to a clipping mask in Illustrator? If so then there is a `background-clip` feature that is described [here on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/) however this is only support in webkit browsers at the moment, I'm not sure about IE10 as this has more added compatibility than other IE versions.

Quickly Google-ing 'Patterned Text with CSS' has shown up [this page](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/textured-and-patterned-text/) which explains it.

**EDIT---------------**

For webkit browsers it is `webkit-background-clip` and for IE9+ it is just `background-clip`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set transparency for text just use:

```
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
```

See more info here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

I don't know if there's a different way of having texturized letters, but you could write a parser for text that will replace letter with image file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a [svg mask](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html) with the piece of text you want to use, then [embed the SVG code directly into the HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp).
This approach should work in most modern browsers.